# How to make a dropdown menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble even getting started.

I want to have a drop down menu that disappears (except for the top box) when you aren't hovering over it.

That top box will appear with a blue background and white text, and an image.

When you hover, that box will turn into a yellow pointing arrow box, and all of the other elements will show, and they will be in black.

Everything will have an image (the now yellow top will keep the same image) and white text.

How do I go about this?

This is essentially what I have here - I'm assuming using jQuery to do this is best.

```
<ul>
<li id="topitem"><img src="blahblahblah1"/>Setup Wizard</li>
<li><img src="blahblahblah2"/>Language</li>
<li><img src="blahblahblah3"/>Password</li>
<li><img src="blahblahblah4"/>Bluetooth Devices</li>
<li><img src="blahblahblah5"/>Network Config</li>
<li><img src="blahblahblah6"/>Finish</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery UI?  I mean, essentially this is just hiding the `ul` element and then tying a hover event on a link.  Pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

you can accomplish this task by creating ul li in Jquery and for those effect use CSS.

```
<style>
        ul.menu {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            list-style: none;
            background-color: beige;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 150px;
        }

        li > ul.subMenu {
            display: none;
            list-style: none;
            background-color: beige;
            font-weight: bold;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        ul.subMenu > li {
            display: block;

        }

        li:hover ul.subMenu {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li> TEST
            <ul class="subMenu">
                <li id="topitem">
                    <img src="blahblahblah1" />Setup Wizard</li>
                <li>
                    <img src="blahblahblah2" />Language</li>
                <li>
                    <img src="blahblahblah3" />Password</li>
                <li>
                    <img src="blahblahblah4" />Bluetooth Devices</li>
                <li>
                    <img src="blahblahblah5" />Network Config</li>
                <li>
                    <img src="blahblahblah6" />Finish</li>
            </u>

        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of tutorials on how to do this out there...I would recommend finding one that you like (style and behavior) and then looking at the jQuery, HTML, and CSS code to see how it works. Here are a couple of links to get you started:

http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: These are great.  I would ask the OP to try to get as far as he could using these resources (and others) and if he's having trouble to repost the question.

Comment: Oh, thanks, these are a lot of useful resources. I was having trouble finding a good way to go about it.

Comment: No problem...as Sethen mentioned, give those a shot and if you have specific trouble come back and post a new question. Also, a good debugger comes in very handy -- something like Firebug will let you troubleshoot HTML, CSS, and scripts right in your browser...can't live without it...